# Collapse similar records in form

Tags: ms-access

I have the following data:

```
Campus Edit Variable
A      1    Y
A      2    Y
B      1    N
B      2    N
C      1    Y
C      2    N
```

We are reviewing the different edit variables that campuses are using. The parent form is the edits. I'd like to have the subform dynamically show the possible variables (in this case Y or N) with the counts of campuses using that variable, and then be able to have a drop down that lists the campuses.

Example:

```
Edit 1
  Variable Y: Count 2 -
    Campus A
    Campus C
  Variable N: Count 1 -
    Campus B
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? I know I can accomplish this with a lot of subforms, but I have about a dozen different types of variables that I will need to build this setup for.

Comment: In your explanation, Campus A has Y for both Edit 1 and Edit 2 values, And Campus B has N for both Edit 1 and Edit 2 values, and although Campus C has Y and N values you have categorised it under Y so why does it not qualify to categorise under N as well? I am asking to better understand how you qualify whether its a Y or N and so be in a better position to possibly help find a solution.

Comment: The parent form is separated by edits. The example is displaying only Edit 1, so therefore campus C, edit 1, has a variable of Y.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look. I'm starting to think the solution is a complicated process. If that's the case, it may be easier to use a series of subforms. The only problem is that I cannot have a continuous form if each record contains a subform.

Comment: If you can access the parent form from the subform then you ought to be able to loop through the Edits and check the edit1 field if its "Y" or "N" and keep a sum/tally/list of the campuses that satisfy your criteria. and output the tally. My access is giving db errors so i cannot test the theory unfortunately.